# Multiple keyword search

Tags: wp-query, search, customization

I have a custom search where I want to enter a keyword or phrase into the search box, and then by pressing enter it adds it to a 'search storage' (already coded, see below). Asume I have 3 posts, one about cars, another and bikes and the final about planes. When this search is made I want all three to display in the results. Currently it would not find anything because there are no posts that contain car, bike and plane keywords individually.

Is it possible to display posts that match each of these keywords? Would I need to do a `wp_query()` for each keyword maybe, inside a `foreach`? Or is there a cleaner way?

[image: screenshot]