# Search Field that allows options of "Match any keyword" or "Match all keywords"

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm having a tough time finding an answer to this question, but searching for the term "search" kind of throws a wrench in everything.

OK so I have a search page where I'm asking the user to enter the words they want to search for. Then I have a dropdown that says "match ALL words" or "match ANY words" - I see this all the time in forum software. How do I adjust the WordPress query to do this? WordPress only seems to have the `s` = 'your search string', where I might want it to be something like an array of terms... `s` = array('your', 'search', 'string') to find posts with any of those words in them.

My question is similar to this one [Multiple keyword search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70475/multiple-keyword-search), but there are no answers, so I'm still looking for help!

Comment: You'll probably want to look at this answer here.  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177183/make-a-wp-query-search-match-exactly-the-search-term

Comment: Yes I believe that will help, thanks! I will update and close once I find the method appropriate for my situation.